Unironic way to say 'you're/that's so kind' or 'thanks for your kindness'
I was wondering how to say "you're/that's so kind!" or "thanks for your kindness!" (after receiving a compliment about my appearance/hair) unironically in Chinese, because I have been told that these phrases (such as 你真友善 or 你非常善良) aren't generally spoken in the language seriously and perceived to be sarcastic. Are there any alternatives/equivalent phrases I can use, apart from just 谢谢?
Thank you!

There are many ways to thank someone who gives a compliment, but saying, in Chinese, that someone is being "kind" is not one of them as it is done in English. You must have searched for Chinese phrases with "kindness" in it when translating, literally, "you're so kind!" which sounds "right" in English, but "strange" in Chinese because the Chinese do not see complimenting someone's good looks as an act of kindness, hence you end up with "你非常善良" & "你真友善" which are totally inappropriate, and may even cause a laugh from the Chinese compliment giver, because 善良 is "kind hearted" & 友善 is "friendly"

To most people, you can say "謝謝你(的讚美)" or just "謝謝(了/啦)", with a big smile when receiving a compliment.
To close friends, you can say "謝謝, 你真好/甜" = "Thank you, you are so nice/sweet".
"你真友善 - You are so friendly" can be said to your friend when his/her compliment essentially is a "mock", for example: "恭喜你又得了個全班倒數第一:)", or "恭喜你又得到了最嘉勇氣獎:)"
"你非常善良" - "You are so kindhearted" is a compliment offered by you to a person who has shown kindness, or done a kind act, toward a third party. It obviously does not fit your purpose but can be used when subjected to mocking.

very useful thank you!

What you say will depend a lot on the situation. If you give a concrete context, then it will be possible to give a specific answer that does not sound strange.
Generally:
你人真好: you are kind
谢谢你对我这么好: thank you for your kindness
With hairstyle as context, you could say this:
Your new hairstyle looks great!
你的新发型看起来很棒！
Thank you, you're very kind.
谢谢, 你很客气.

Thanks, they were complimenting my appearance (hair). Would these words still be ok to use with this context?
